# Flask restful parser list dictionary

Tags: rest, flask

I have an example parse request list dictionary:

```
{
    "shopping_cart": [{
        "id": 23323,
        "qty": 10
    }, {
        "id": 34232,
        "qty": 9
    }, {
        "id": 34232,
        "qty": 9
    }]
}
```

How can i parse it use flask_restful RequestParser ?

Comment: funny, I'm trying to parse a much simpler dictionary with both RequestParser and `marshal` but no luck. It seems that REST API programming in Flask is in inceptional state for years and everyone is happy using Djano

Answer (score 15):

Use something like this :)

```
self.postreqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
self.postreqparse.add_argument("shopping_cart", type=dict, action="append")
```