# Flask API Post list of dictionaries

Tags: python, http-post, flask-restful

I have a list of dictionaries that I want to post using Flask Swagger API. The data looks something like this:

```
dummy_data = {'person':[{'name' : John, 'Age': 67}, 
                        {'name' : Jane, 'Age': 66}
              ]}
```

The follow is my parser:

```
ParserPost = reqparse.RequestParser()
ParserPost.add_argument("person", type=list, action='append')

@api.expect(ParserPost)
def post(self):
     args = ParserPost.parse_args()
     print(args)
```

The output return `{person: None}`

I can't seem to figure out why. According to the [Flask Documentation](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reqparse.html), the code should work fine.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35764851/flask-restful-parser-list-dictionary) seems to have the same issue as I had but its solution doesn't work in my case.

Comment: `action='append'` - what should it *append to*? Have you tried omitting that?

Comment: Yes I did, still no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to convert the list of dictionaries into a string format and then passing the string to the back end.

```
let dummy_dict = {'person': JSON.stringify(dummy_data)}
```

The parser is as follow:

```
ParserPost = reqparse.RequestParser()
ParserPost.add_argument("person", type=str)

@api.expect(ParserPost)
def post(self):
     args = ParserPost.parse_args()
```

And then use `ast.literal_eval(args['person'])` to convert the string into its intended datatype. Not the most elegant method but it works.